# Is it possible to just parse the SAML assertion response without authenticating with IDP?

Tags: saml-2.0

I'm facing a problem with validating SAML response where in, its giving digest mismatch. Tried checking it with the certificate's digest value and its showed a different value. I think there is a problem with the certificate or the SAML response but, I'm also wondering whether not having an authentication at the SP level is also a cause for concern since, the client does not want a response back on the IDP, contrary to what the standard setup for SAML dictates. I realize there shouldn't be a setup of this sort due to obvious security concerns but, this was the setup they have requested...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the SAML assertion is not signed properly, this is a security concern and you should not trust it. By trusting it without validating the digest, you would open your self up to anyone submitting SAML to your ACS URL and being authenticated.